# Refresh folder under WebContent by java program (in eclipse project)

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I ‘m making a WEB system (latest Java8 & eclipse_mars.2  on Windows 32x) . 
And this system has file download function (files are made by java). 
When files(for download) are placed in myproject/WebContent/tempfolder ,
And users can access these files by URL and can get files.

(I want to manage Web system under Eclipse Control. Not on Tomcat)

But files (made by java) are not recognized immediately by eclipse.
In my prepairing server condition,
 when I press download button on this system , I must wait about 7--8 seconds.

Users would not allow 7--8 seconds  waiting (I think).

(eclipse workspace setting ((window)-(preferences)-(general)-(workspace)) is like this: 
・Refresh on native hook or polling(checked)
・Refresh on access(checked)
)
I researched programatcally refresh plugin in many WEB site, but I could not find this.

So I started to make Eclipse-Plugin ,
   to make myproject/WebContent/tempfolder to be refreshed programmatically,
 just after java program set a new file to be downloaded..

(Now, workspace name is “myworkspace_m”.
Dinamic Web Project name is “myproject”.
 The folder to be refreshed is “myproject/WebContent/tempfolder”.
 Plugin Project name is “myprojectsupport”.
Refresh program is “RefreshFolder.java”. )

The program in Eclipse plugin project is as below .(It does’t work)

```
package myprojectsupport;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.*;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath;

public class RefreshFolder {

    public void main() throws CoreException {
        IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
        IProject project = root.getProject("myproject");
        IPath path = project.getFullPath().append("WebContent/tempfolder");
        IFile iFile  = root.getFile(path);

        iFile.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
   }
}
```

When I run this program,
I opened myprojectsupport\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF,
and on OverView tab, I press the link of “launch an eclipse application ”

Then open another eclipse window ,and  console said like bellow.
But I can’t understand this console log.
Please advise me what should I do .
(Sorry for bad English)

```
!SESSION 2016-06-11 17:52:57.414 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500
java.version=1.8.0_92
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=ja_JP
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -data C:\myworkspace_m/../runtime-EclipseApplication -dev file:C:/myworkspace_m/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2016-06-11 17:53:02.051
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2016-06-11 17:53:02.051
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for ALT+F5:
Binding(ALT+F5,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(com.github.ugrave.tools.ws.refresh.commands.RefreshWorkspaceHandler,Refresh Workspace,
        Refresh the complete Workspace,
        Category(org.eclipse.core.commands.categories.autogenerated,Uncategorized,Commands that were either auto-generated or have no category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@b94590,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(ALT+F5,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.command.updateProject,Update Project,
        Update Maven Project configuration and dependencies,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.window,Window,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@177fc44,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://933.fwk28054045:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://933.fwk28054045:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2016-06-11 17:53:04.854
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\s111111'. 
If this is not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. 
Otherwise Git for Windows and EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 4 0 2016-06-11 17:53:07.437
!MESSAGE WinHttp.DetectAutoProxyConfigUrl for wpad failed with error 'vLV̎©®\¬ ' #12180.
```

Comment: You have to install an Eclipse plugin in to your current Eclipse, and the plugin can't just have a `main` method it must be hooked up to a menu item or something like that. You need to read a tutorial on writing plugins.

Comment: Thank you for drop comment. But please add to explain Eclipse plugin name which should be installed . my eclipse is "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers " mars.2 . it looks like Plugin development tools in it.

Comment: This is far to complex for a Stack Overflow answer, you need to go through a full plugin tutorial because your current code is completely wrong.

Comment: Why do you insist on storing the content as a file under WebContent? I mean, why do not you return the file content directly from your Webapp?

Comment: Thank you very much for coments..

Comment: Thank you very much for comment.. I would try to read out the tutorial. I'm not native English speaker so this document seemed difficult.        And reason why I want to set files on temp folder  is I think files should be hidden usually ,so files are placed on another  folder , when users request to download then files should be set on temp folder, so users can get  one file each time   .And next reason is amount of all files is big (may be 400GB),so if i set all files under workspace ,eclipse make meta files about 200 GB and ,disk will be  over capacity.